# Cannot display Label or LabelTTF in cocos2d-x Windows?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

My project after the build up it displays this
(I am sorry, I can not upload by image tab)

http://www.mediafire.com/download/x7jb77osu8vq6xz/2.png

Previously I had been running successfully, but now the label can not be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't yet checked your code, (which you can paste it here instead of linking to mediafire). Most probable cause can be that you didn't specify the z-order of label. You need to specify the z-order while adding anything to layer (sprite, label, menu etc etc). This is actually a bug in 3.0 I reported that on forums, not sure if it's fixed in latest version.

Comment: I don't change code. The link to mediafire is the photos that I took back as soon as I use Cocos command "cocos new [projectname] ..." to create new a application and then I used to Cocos command "cocos run ..." to build it.

Comment: oh ok, I checked the image. Can you paste the code of HelloWordLayer init method? Are you adding label, which is not visible?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help!
I tried adding menu items, but they can not show too.
Link to classes: https://www.mediafire.com/?whd749ft4omqbc8
Link to new problem: https://www.mediafire.com/?qgfc4pp7sc4spd9